# How we identify the relation direction in an ER diagram if we use Chens notation?

Tags: uml, entity-relationship

How we identify the relationship direction in `Chen notation`?. If we add **A has B relationship** then can anyone read it as **B has A** ?

Comment: I know that in the uml notation this is possible.we can add a text to describe the relation and an arrow to show the directions.Is such kind of possibility there for Chens notation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I found an answer for my question after a long time. It is the name of the relationship which provides the direction of the relationship in chen's notation.

[image]

This image describe it well

Comment: I have the same question 2 years later and I could not find any good resources. I think that the naming is a bit weak but I suppose you are right, that is all we have...